# table info has no column named Desc while compiling insert

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, insert, sql-insert

```
package pdatabase.rakesh.phobia.pdatabase;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

class MyDatabase {

    public static final String DB_NAME = "Tasks.db";
    public static final int DB_VER = 2;
    public static final String DB_TABLE = "Info";
    public static final String C_TASK = "task";
    public static final String C_DESC = "desc";
    public static final String Q_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE "+ DB_TABLE + " (C_TASK TEXT, C_DESC TEXT)";
    Context context;
    SQLiteDatabase database;

    public MyDatabase(Context c) {
        context = c;
    }

    public MyDatabase open() {
        DBHelper dbh = new DBHelper(context);
        database = dbh.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void write(String task, String desc) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(C_TASK, task);
        cv.put(C_DESC, desc);
        database.insert( DB_TABLE,null, cv);
    }

    public void close() {
        database.close();
    }

    public String read() {
        String result = "";

        String[] colms = {C_TASK,C_DESC};
        Cursor cur = database.query(DB_TABLE, colms,null,null,null,null,null);

        int iTask=cur.getColumnIndex(C_TASK);
        int iDesc=cur.getColumnIndex(C_DESC);

        for(cur.moveToFirst(); !cur.isAfterLast(); cur.moveToNext()){
            result = result + cur.getString(iTask) + "\t" + cur.getString(iDesc) + "\n";
        }
        return result;
    }

    private class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

        public DBHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DB_NAME,null, DB_VER);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL(Q_CREATE);

        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        }
    }
}
```

In the above code I can't neither read nor write C_DESC. I am getting the error as written in topic of this post in android studio. This is my database class responsible for all database operations. It can write as well as read if and only if C_TASK is present. In case both are present it could not work. The app purpose is to save the task and description and view it.

Comment: `desc` is a reserved word in SQL, so your code probably doesn't work.  It is not obvious that you are checking for errors.  You should fix your code so you capture errors.

Comment: I changed desc to descr wherever required still getting error at line code:: 
  database.insert( DB_TABLE,null, cv);

Comment: In logcat 09-23 19:28:17.964 26075-26075/pdatabase.rakesh.phobia.pdatabase E/SQLiteLog: (1) table Info has no column named descr
09-23 19:28:17.976 26075-26075/pdatabase.rakesh.phobia.pdatabase E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting descr=hcch task=jvf
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table Info has no column named descr (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO Info(descr,task) VALUES (?,?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've created a table with the actual column name `C_DESC` instead of using the content of that variable. Note, by the way, that `desc` is a reserved word in SQL, so if you absolutely must use it as a column name, you should escape it by surrounding it with double quotes (`"`):

```
public static final String Q_CREATE = 
    "CREATE TABLE "+ DB_TABLE + " (" + 
    "\"" + C_TASK + "\" TEXT, " + 
    "\"" + C_DESC + "\" TEXT)";
```